# Gorm problem with Pluck and Scan columns into different variables/structs with Pluck?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have got the following table after grouping a little over my main table

```sql
col1  |count|   
------+-----+   
test1 |12123|   
test2 | 1323|   
test3 | 4223|   
test4 | 1031|
```

I now want to get this into my struct:

```golang
type Lalala struct {
 test1: int64
 test2: int64
 test3: int64
 test4: int64
}
```

I have one solution, where I put down a struct for each column and then get the entire array of it, afterwards I use a switch case to parse the counts into my struct. But this seems kinda wonky.

I was hoping something like this works:

```golang
var response Lalala
....Group("col1").
    Pluck("count", gorm.Expr("col1= test1"), &response.test1). // Either smth like this
    Pluck("count", gorm.Expr("col1= test2")).Scan(&response.test2).Error // Or like this? tho this ignores the Pluck kinda and aint working
```

Any help or another way to parse this resulting table into the struct would be quite useful, I don't feel like my above mentioned array and switch solution looks like best practice.

EDIT: also what I am wondering in this whole attempt of mine, when I say Pluck("count", &[]int) it doesn't work, which I am confused, I only want the count array here, but I have to pass a struct that has `{col1:string,count:int64}`
=> Seems like Pluck gives me a ROW instead of a COLUMN

My current solution is an Pluck => offset => Pluck => ...